# QT Wrong Calculation Result

Tags: c++, qt

I stomped with this problem, i have tried several things but no luck yet. I'm testing a program and using the following parameters: `double totalLoss=18.40`, `int totalCases=1000`. If you lose 18.4% of the 1000 boxes you should have 816 boxes left. The output variable `afterPackCases` is a `double` as well.

```
  qDebug()<<"Total Loss:"<<QString::number(totalLoss,'f',4);
  qDebug()<<"Total Cases:"<<QString::number(totalCases,'f',4);
  ui->totalLoss->setText(QString::number(totalLoss,'f',2));
  afterPackCases=((double)totalCases * (100.0-totalLoss)) / 100.0;
  qDebug()<<"After Pack:"<<QString::number(afterPackCases,'f',4);
```

And here is the debug output:

```
Total Loss: "18.4000"
Total Cases: "1000.0000"
After Pack: "815.0000"
```

Where is the box I lost?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://ideone.com/GLq8J9

Comment: I've tested your code and it works fine:   `double totalLoss =18.40;
    int totalCases = 1000;
    double afterPackCases;
   qDebug()<<"Total Loss:"<<QString::number(totalLoss,'f',4);
    qDebug()<<"Ttal Cases:"<<QString::number(totalCases,'f',4);
    afterPackCases=totalCases * (100.0-totalLoss) / 100.0;
    qDebug()<<"After Pack:"<<QString::number(afterPackCases,'f',4);` *output*: `Total Loss: "18.4000"
Total Cases: "1000.0000"
After Pack: "816.0000"`

Comment: You could show how you declare and assign variables

Comment: Maybe some of your variables is changed somewhere else, i.e. in another thread?

Comment: Sorry, i answer my own question. I lied, afterRepack was an int, the floating point calculation was probably giving 815.99999999999999, when assigned to the int the decimal part was lost. Solved using by changing afterRepack to double.

Comment: You should improve your mvce, if you do not know what it is read the following:[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should fix the example with the actual code and self-answer your question.